# How to share single Viewmodel in two or more views?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I know in MVVM we should not use viewModel accross the views, but my applications needs it. So I have a view and corresponding ViewModel

Say LinkView and LinkViewModel

in LinkWindow Constructor

```
public LinkWindow(string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LinkViewModel vm = new LinkViewModel(path);
    this.DataContext = vm;     
}
```

So LinkWindow and its corrosponding LinkViewModel is initialize. Now in the LinkWindow I have one button that will Pops up one more window(As and when required) but I require the same viewModel instance (vm)

The button implements Command `"LinkEmailCommand"`

```
LinkEmailCommand = new Command(DoEmailCommand, false);
```

In the `LinkViewModel`

```
private void DoEmailCommand()
{
    var EmailWindow = new EmailWindow();
    EmailWindow.Show();
}
```

This EmailWindow does not use the LinkViewModel that's already initialize. How do I do that?

EDIT- Solution:

So what's the solution is pass "this" in the constructor

In the `LinkViewModel`

```
private void DoEmailCommand()
{
    var EmailWindow = new EmailWindow(this);
    EmailWindow.Show();
}
```

then in the LinkWindow pass the viewModel object in one of the constructor

```
public LinkWindow(LinkViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = FilrUI.Properties.Resources.ShareFilrEmail;
            this.DataContext = vm;
        }
```

that's all now a single instance of a viewmodel can be used in two views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create viewModel in other class, then pass it to both of your views constructors :)

```
public LinkWindow(string path, object viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;    
}
```

Same way in second view. Just use the same viewModel object instance

Comment: Viewmodel Initialize is done in the linkWindow.cs file and LinkWindow.DataContext = vm; now How do I Initilize ViewModel in the command of DoEmailCommand()?

Comment: So pass the current (already initialized) ViewModel to your second view

    var EmailWindow = new EmailWindow(this);
    EmailWindow.Show();

And in EmailWindow's Constructor pass it to DataContext property

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly, I have updated my code so that others will get benefited.

Answer (score 2):

> I know in MVVM we should not use viewModel accross the views

Why do you think so? 
It's a very common practice - to have several ways to represent the same data.

```
private void DoEmailCommand()
{
    // do not do this!
    var EmailWindow = new EmailWindow(); 
    EmailWindow.Show();
}
```

You shouldn't create views from your view models. This kills one of the benefits of MVVM - code testability and brings the close coupling between view models and views. Consider using services or event aggregators to display new views.

> How do I do that?

Obviously, two views need the same instance of view model. The simplest thing you can do is to pass view model instance into `EmailWindow` constructor or assign view model for `EmailWindow` through the property.

Answer (score 1):

In `EmailWindow` add a property `ViewModel`. Then simply do this in your command handler :

```
private void DoEmailCommand()
{
    var EmailWindow = new EmailWindow();
    EmailWindow.ViewModel = vm;
    EmailWindow.Show();
}
```

Of course you would also need to refactor your `LinkWindow` to have the vm as a field. Like so :

```
// Field for the viewmodel
private LinkViewModel vm;

public LinkWindow(string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new LinkViewModel(path);
    this.DataContext = vm;     
}
```

Comment: What will be that property ViewModel? LinkViewModel right? ok but LinkWindow and its initialization is done in constructors. It is in the View.cs not in ViewModel

Comment: Yes the ViewModel type should be LinkViewModel. It is not relevant where the initialization happens. You have all the necessary references available to you. So given your code sample you should be able to get it working. If you have trouble just post your view and viewmodel .cs files as an edit to your question. That way we will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: If I write public LinkWindow(string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new LinkViewModel(path);
    this.DataContext = vm;     
} in the LinkViewModel, First InitializeComponent(); shows error, and then in the LinkWindow we are passing a new instance of the LinkViewModel, but I want the same instance.

Comment: Yes. That's why I wrote that you need to have the field on the LinkViewModel class that will store the reference to the viewmodel.